# ROR rspec-rails error: ActiveRecord: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec-rails

I am doing the RoR requests test and I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
  connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# PG::ConnectionBad:
#   connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
#   ./spec/rails_helper.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
```

And this is my test code for it:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    before(:example) { get "/users" }

    it 'is a success' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end

    it "renders 'index' template" do
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end

    it "shows the rendered text 'Welcome to the Ruby on Rails Blog'" do
      expect(response).to include('Welcome to the Ruby on Rails Blog')
    end
  end
end
```

I provided my username and password in database.yml and I don't know why get this error.
My config for database.yml

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_app
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: {username}
  password: {password}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the development database. Tests run under a different one.

Add the following to your `database.yml`.

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_blog_app
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: {username}
  password: {password}
```