# How can I setup correctly Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed Ruby Version 3.1.2p20 and Rails Version Rails 7.0.4.
So I want to create new rails app and when I type rails new test-app I am getting error related to UTF-8. Does anyone has any recommendation or can help me setup Rails app correctly? Thanks in advance.

I tried many solutions, but I am thinking I should reinstall it all. Also I checked PATH and it is correctly added.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is the issue here with Ruby 3.1 in windows. But as we know that Ruby's default encoding since 2.0 is UTF-8. This means that Ruby will treat any string as a UTF-8 encoded string unless you tell it explicitly that it's encoded differently so I am guessing there might be something wrong in `pathname.rb` file.

I faced the same issue in windows and I resolved it by downgrading ruby from 3.1 to 2.7 and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed it, but now I have a new error. 
Error: 

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: You need to specify the development database. Please see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132261/ror-rspec-rails-error-activerecord-connection-to-server-at-localhost-1
Also, please Upvote my answer if it helped you in any way :).